# How can i determine the maximum value in a list of tuples?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, max, rdd

my problem is a little bit complicated.. Actually as i asked before, i'm working with some biological data which are proteins. For each protein i have the **name** and it's **annotation**, for example:

`(B8DG74,2.7.8.7)`

Each protein have a list of neighbors, the groupByKey function in spark helped me to determine it, and they are separated by semicolon. So the list of neighbors looks like:

`(Q9LD43,2.1.3.15,1.0);(Q85X25,2.1.3.15,0.4);(Q6HCT2,2.1.3.15,0.7854127);(Q8Y6V8,2.1.3.15,0.14285715)`

As you can see, each neighbor is a tuple containing the neighbor name `Q9LD43` for example, its annotation `2.1.3.15` and another value which is the linkweight `1.0`.

More clearly, the linkweight between `B8DG74` and `Q9LD43`  equals to `1.0`.

How can I, based on this list of neighbors, determine the protein having the maximum link weight with our input protein?

Here's my try:

```
s.map(l=> {
      val (prot, annot) = l._1
      val listneighbors = l._2.toList //list of neighbors

      if (annot == "null")
       {
         for ( i <- listneighbors) { // the i is a tuple
         
           val neighbor_name = i._1
           val neighbor_annot = i._2
           val linkweight = i._3
           
           println("the max link weight between " + prot + " and its neighbors is " + linkweight.max)}
```

Comment: what is the format of "s"?

Comment: it's an rdd containing all those data

Comment: So l._1 is B8DG74 and l._2 is "2.7.8.7" ?

Comment: You probably want `maxBy` - BTW, I would use pattern matching to increase the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can use pattern matching for simplify your code. I think it's help you. For more detailed answer you should provide more data about your dataset, e.g., you can print scheme of DF.

```scala
object StackOverflow extends App {
  type Neighbor = (String, String, Double) // human-readable type alias for tuple 
  val source: List[((String, String), List[Neighbor])] = {
    val neighbors: List[Neighbor] = List(
      ("Q9LD43", "2.1.3.15", 1.0),
      ("Q85X25", "2.1.3.15", 0.4),
      ("Q6HCT2", "2.1.3.15", 0.7854127),
      ("Q8Y6V8", "2.1.3.15", 0.14285715)
    )
    val firstItem = (("prot", "annot"), neighbors)
    val secondItem = (("prot", "null"), neighbors)
    List(firstItem, secondItem)
  }
  source.map {
    case ((protein, annot), neighbors) if annot == "null" => // maybe you should use `annot == null`
      val (neighborName, neighborAnnot, linkWeight) = neighbors.maxBy(_._3)
      println("the max link weight between " + protein + " and its neighbors is " + linkWeight)
    case _ => // do nothing
  }
}
```